# Rails 4, Route with multiple ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make a route like this `/p/:id/:ph_id`. and the `:ph_id` also has limitation on length  `/\d{7}/`

This is what I have for the first id

```
 scope '/p', :controller => 'people' do
   scope '/:id', :id => /\d{7}/ do end
 end
```

Comment: it's hard to help without any context. what is p? if it has an id, shouldn't it be a resource?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `config/routes.rb` try following code:

```
get "/p/:id/:ph_id" => "people#show", as: :my_route, id: /\d{7}/, ph_id: /\d{7}/
```

You can use it like:

```
<%= link_to "Check this link!", my_route_path(id: 1234567, ph_id: 7654321) %>
```

Hope that helps! Good Luck!